# Search on array elements in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to search two or more values on array and get only those ones that match with all words (AND CLAUSE)

Some example:

```
   { "name" : "Chevrolet",
      "value" : [ "gasolina", "alcool", "diesel"]
   }    
   { "name" : "Fiat",
      "value" : [ "eletrica", "alcool"]
   }
   { "name" : "Honda",
      "value" : [ "diesel", "gasolina"]
   }
```

My mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "cars": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "GasType": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "GasType",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": {"GasType.value": "gasolina"}},
            { "match": {"GasType.value": "diesel"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My return is always empty and if i change de query i have got all those that contains "Gasolina" or "diesel"
I need those that has "Gasolina" AND "diesel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test data doesn't match the mapping of the index. In your test data I don't see the nested field name `GasType`. In any case, the following works for me just fine:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "cars": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "GasType": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/cars/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Chevrolet","GasType":{"value":["gasolina","alcool","diesel"]}}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Fiat","GasType":{"value":["eletrica","alcool"]}}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Honda","GasType":{"value":["diesel","gasolina"]}}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"Honda","GasType":{"value":["diesel"]}}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "GasType",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "GasType.value": "gasolina"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "GasType.value": "diesel"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```